# RShiny Downloading Highchart Graphs (Multiple Graphs at Once)

Tags: javascript, r, ggplot2, highcharts

Does anyone have any familiarity or examples of how to download multiple charts in rshiny with  highcharter (exactly like this example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/multiple-charts-offline/ but through the download handler in rShiny)?

I can download plots and ggplot with the download handler, but am struggling to use the download handler with the highchart plots. It results in an error file 'export.html'. I have no problem with the chart library when I export from the corner of the image, but I want to download via the handler so I can do multiple charts on one page. I have tried printing the graphs to pdf or jpeg and also just plotting them to the download handler. All resulted in error. Any help or redirection to the appropriate contact would be much appreciated! Below is an example download handler I tried to make with hw_grid (similar to the grid.arrange() in ggplot).

```
output$export = downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {"plots.pdf"},
      content = function(file) {
        pdf(file, onefile = TRUE)
        hw_grid(vals$p1, vals$p2,vals$p3,vals$p4, ncol = 2) 
        dev.off()
      }
    )
```

Vals is an array of renderHighchart plots (hcharts).